# lavaral 5 ERROR{ (SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)}

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
  'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

**JUST CHANGED THE CODE FOR LOCALHOST AND  CHANNGED THE NAME TO ROOT AND SET THE PASSWORD OF PHPMYADMIN . **

**WHEN WRITTING  THE COMMAND IN XAMPP SHELL ((Php artisan migrate:install)) **

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'password'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'password'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

**it is showing error   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

Comment: try to put credentials in `.env` file in root.

Comment: ok. thanks. dont be rude man.. i am just a learner

Comment: Please read this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#environment-configuration You can revert the changes on the file you changed, and enter your database credentials in the .env file like Shravan Shrama mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default laravel assumes that you will want to have different configurations for different environments. E.g. in a testing environment, you might wish to have a different username and password and in a production environment different. Since laravel has so many configuration files, it quickly becomes a nightmare to manage all those. Hence laravel makes use of PHP's environment variables.

[See the docs here.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration)

What is basically says is that if you wish to use the "environment" variables, which laravel uses by default, you have to place all your configurations in the `env()` method as already mentioned.

If you do not wish to do this, e.g. for simple projects, simply remove the env from your code, like this.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Note that you can mix and match. i.e you can have some of the variables in env and some stand-alone.

## So why use `env` at all?

Lets say your application has 100 testers all placed in different locations. In laravel you have to code approximately 8-10 configuration files. Also you need to `version-control` those files. So you have two problems at hand:

1. You do not wish to send all 100 users the same credentials. Also they might use different database, cache server, etc which means that they will have different configurations. So every user has to maintain those 8-10 configuration files by hand.
2. You do not wish to send these configuration files to version control. Because if you do, whole world will know your API secrets and possibly will take advantage of that (just like password). Also if you look at laravel conf files, you will notice that there are other information such as timezone, debug property, etc that are also in conf files, and you do want to version-control them. So how do you version-control such configuration files and still hide your sensitive information.

The answer is `env` variables. Laravel uses `dotenv` whose [documentation can be found here](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). Basically these are variables that live in one file called `.env` in a key-value pair. E.g.

**Sample contents of .env file**

```
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=ABCDEFGH
...
```

Once you define your .env file as this, you can get the value using the key as such `env('APP_DEBUG')`.

So this solves the above mentioned problem in following ways:

1. you keep the `.env` file to yourself. And you also declare another file called `.env.example` which is an exact replica of original file except the fact that it contains sample values, not your sensitive values. Then you pass this new example file to everyone. They will replace the sample data with their own sensitive information.
2. Since you are version-controlling the example file, you can version control all your conf files because they don't contain the secret. The secret is in .env files. All those conf files contain is values like these `env('APP_KEY')` and the actual value is replaced at run time using your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have to set up right server credentials into `.env` file on your Laravel project:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myapp_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Try to clean up artisan cache and restart the artisan,

```
php artisan config:clear 
restart php artisan
```