# Laravel 5 project initial settings best practices

Tags: php, laravel, singleton, laravel-5

I have an app that stores config settings into the database

the database table is consisted of two text columns, `key` and `value`.

I want to read all the values ONCE in the start of my app and then make it available to the whole app through

`MySettings::set(key, value)`
and
`MySettings::get(key)`

I believe the best way is to make it through `$app->singleton` but since I am new to Laravel I really can't seem to understand how this could be accomplished :(

And of cource, if there is a better way to do it (without singleton) I would be glad to know how.

Answer (score 3):

Usually people keep their configuration details in the `.env` file. Read about [env in laravel docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration). I wrote a [lengthy article about the use of env here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139599/lavaral-5-error-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhos/31142295#31142295). Keeping values in database is not necessary and probably not recommended until you have some other configuration where you are required to keep conf values in database.

But if you want to do it, you can get all the variables from database and keep it in `PHP superglobal variables`. [Read about it here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Take your pic from these variables and carefully read about them all and why they are used. Then choose the one which best suits you. `$_ENV` is the one that seems to fit in your case.

You said:

> I want to read all the values ONCE in the start of my app

I think you have not clearly understood the whole request response phase. There is no such thing as "start" of you app. Every time a request comes to the server, your application boots up, prepares all the variables and loads them in memory. Once the response is send, everything is destroyed. Hence even if you will keep a singleton class, it will be created again and again upon each request. However, session, cookie, etc are persistent and they don't go away.

## Update 1:

So it turns out **using superglobal variables is considered a bad practice**. So coming back to the original question - how to create a singleton class in Laravel. Assuming we are on L5, we can simply:

1. Autoload composer.json
2. Follow the namespaces.

Both these techniques are [nicely explained here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/l5-how-to-add-my-own-custom-class).

---

## Update 2: How to create singleton classes in L5 as a `Provider`

Now this is a pretty neat technique that I came to know recently and this matches exactly with the needs of the asker.

Based on the Laravel architecture, when a request is received on server side, laravel boots up and `binds` some services like `Auth`, `Cache`, etc. Similarly you can also bind your own `Provider` so that at the time of bootup your class will automatically will be instantiated and you can use them throughout your app.

**Step 1:** Create a `ServiceProvider` using php artisan command:

```
php artisan make:provider DatabaseConfigurationServiceProvider
```

This will make a provider in your `Providers` folder.

**Step 2:** Fill in your new class like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\DatabaseConfigurationService;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DatabaseConfigurationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('dbconf', function() {
            return new DatabaseConfigurationService();
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['dbconf'];
    }
}
```

So what we have done here is:

- Extended the `ServiceProvider`. All providers have to do this.
- Made `defer` to true because we don't want to load this configuration on each request. Instead we want to load this class when we need it. In-case you want to load your configurations on each request, then you make this value to true and then also remove the whole `provides()` function because we dont need it anymore. What then would happen is that every time a new request comes, this class will be called and it will load all your database conf values and will store them until the request is processed.
- We then overrided the `register()` method to register this provider with the class you want to call. We registered a name `dbconf` which then becomes the identifier for the global `$app` variable and we also binded a class `DatabaseConfigurationService()`. Note that this class will be defined later. Also note that this `class is binded in a`singleton`fashion` meaning that it will only be instantiated once.
- We then created a `provides()` method which is ONLY required when you have `$defer` set to true. This returns the bindings name that should be loaded when this class is loaded.

**Step 3:** Create the `DatabaseConfigurationService` class.

To do this step you need to create a new folder `Services` in the app folder. Then write this code.

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class DatabaseConfigurationService
{
    public static $somevar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Do some tasks such as getting username/password from your .env file
    }

    public static function getValues()
    {
        //Get all your values here.
    }
}
```

What we have done here is:

- Created this class which will be called by the `Provider` class at the time application is booted up/required (depends on the $defer).

**Step 4:** Create a `Facade` for your new provider:

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class DatabaseConfiguration extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'dbconf';
    }
}
```

**Step 5:** Make these changes in `config/app.php`

- Add the below line in the `provider` array.

  App\Providers\DatabaseConfigurationServiceProvider
- Add the below line in the aliases array.

  'DatabaseConfiguration '=> 'App\Facades\DatabaseConfiguration'

**Step 6:** Finally you can now use your `Provider` in your controller like this:

**Note:** I know its a bit lengthy process, but its the recommended way. Once you make a couple of `Providers` you will understand that its a fairly easy process.
 - Import the facade using: `use DatabaseConfiguration;`
 - Call the methods of this class using `DatabaseConfiguration::getValues()`

Comment: The administrator should be able to change the values anytime, through a web interface, so `env` approach is out of question.
When I mentioned ONCE, I ment once in every request. So I think that you have not clearly undertood the question.
I want all the CONF key/values to be retrieved ONCE in the start of the request, and get them through `MySettings::get(key)` whenever it is needed. I just dont want to hit the DB every time I want to get a value.
And I don't realy like the idea of superglobals

Comment: @Krisi Sorry for my misunderstanding. But why not superglobals?? Also you can create a file that return an array. Populate that array at each request and include it wherever you needed. Your singleton class approach is also correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply superglobals is Evil. the file that creates the array is out of the question because i said I have to read from the database.

Comment: @Krisi I read a few articles about why using superglobals are bad - thanks for the info man...I learned something new. So returning to your orig ques, how to make a singleton class. Assuming you in L5, you can create the class normally, and then could autoload them, or just follow the namespace in your singleton class. I will update my answer with additional details.

Comment: @Krisi Please see my updated comment. Its exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement your own Singleton, it could make it easier for you to understand what's actually happening:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class Settings
{
    private static $instance;

    private static $settings = [];

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(is_null(static::$instance)) 
            static::$instance= new Settings;

        return static::$settings;
    }

    public static function getKey($key)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($key , static::$settings))
            return static::$settings[$key];
        return null;
    }

    public static function setKey($key , $value)
    {
        static::$settings[$key] = $value;
    }

}

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
//...

class HelloController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        Settings::getInstance();
        Settings::setKey("foo", "bar");
        Settings::getKey("foo"); // returns bar
        // as long as you don't change "foo" again, it will always be "bar" anywhere in your app
    }
}
```

1. Create a folder inside the app folder and call it Helpers
2. Create Settings.php inside the Helpers folder
3. run "Composer dump-autoload" in the laravel directory ( not the app directory )